# Russian journal name not printed correctly in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, babel, russian

I am trying to include some resources from Russian and other languages in my bibliography. With the MWE I have here everything is fine, but it fails to print the journal name correctly.

The ideal case is that I do not have to define language and hyphenation as the desired language for each resource.

But even trying to include Russian language option in my bibitem, it does not seem to work and I get an error.

Is there any way to fix it in a not too complicated way?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,german,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}
some text \cite{russian}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My test.bib file content:

```
  @article{russian,
  title={Курс общей физики, том III. Оптика, атом ная физика, физика атомного ядра и элементарных частиц},
  author={Савельев, ИВ},
  journal={ Курс общей физики, том III.},
  year={1973},  
}
```

[image]

I put a part of the title into journal section name to show what I get correctly in the title is printed in an awkward way in journal title part.

Comment: Mhhh, but isn't that they way Cyrillic looks in italics?

Comment: I thought so at the beginning, but after checking upper and lower case Russian alphabets, noticed here t is printed as m... which is obviously wrong even to my non-Russian eyes.

Comment: Nope, that is correct, Russian italics looks more like handwriting, which looks a bit particular for us non-Russians.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_cursive and [Why does italic 'т' look like 'm'](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1552)

Comment: If you don't want italic, you could try with `\slshape`

Comment: silly me! never thought letters will look this different in their italic form and only checked the lower case letters! should I delete this question?

Comment: Well, that depends. Do you think you can spin it in a way you get a TeX-related answer?

Comment: I feel like other non-Russians will come across this question putting stuff in bibliography... Only in that sense, it is related to latex... and they will know this is how italic Russian looks like!

Comment: You might want to check the entry type of your source, I don't think it really is a journal article. It looks more like a chapter/part/book of a multi-volume collection to me.

Comment: it's not an actual journal I am using, I just google translated some word and looked for it in scholar google...

Comment: Ah okay, I see.

Comment: I can only add that the word "атомная" ("nuclear") somehow got split into two  ("атом ная"), which will be understood but is still a typo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The output you get is correct. The journal name is set in italics. Russian italics look more like the handwriting, where some letters have shapes differing from their upright shapes. See [*Why does italic 'т' look like 'm'*  over at Russian.SX](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1552), [Wikipedia on Cyrillic script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) and [Russian cursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_cursive), [Russian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet).

Comment: @egreg The default setting is `language=autobib`, so only the bibliography language is switched according to `langid`. That causes troubles because the citation label also wants Cyrillic. We need `language=auto` to switch both bibliography and citations to `other*`.

Comment: I realized it, so I removed my comment. What's probably needed here is that the reference uses a transcription: if the main language is English, a Cyrillic author name in the text would be quite strange.

Comment: @egreg Mhhh, maybe. Unfortunately, development of the multiscript version of `biblatex`, that would have enabled this and probably much more, seems to have stalled.

Comment: and How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @Prelude Sorry, what issue? If you use `\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}` you will need to mark Russian entries as Russian with`langid = {russian}` (you can also give `language = {russian}` if you want) and use `language=auto, autolang=other*`.